# Copy entire column in another column as a value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am have a column that is obtained with a formula like this:

```
=A1&","&B1
```

Now I need to copy the content (as the value, result of the formula) from every cell of that column in another column.

```
text1,text2
```

I tried with copy and paste as a value but it doesn't work for the whole column but only for few entries. Do you have any idea how I could solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Did you filter your data? If you then copy and paste it will copy the visible data, but if you paste it will paste in the cells that are filtered out as well.

Comment: @P.b Yes I am in filtering mode. I tried to do that without filtering and it worked. But still, after that I need to copy all the values of that column only in certain cells of another. In filtering mode I cannot do that. If I do that in normal mode I will overwrite other cells too. Do you have any idea how could I solve? Thanks

Comment: My goal is to add ",text2" in all the filtered column

Comment: Maybe a simple workaround is to copy the filtered data and paste them I am unfiltered new/other sheet.